# Reporting python interactive mode examples as in the introduction

Tags: beamer, python, syntax-highlighting

I would like to imitate the style used in the [python introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)

within my beamer slides.

Essentialy, I would like an environment with some background that colors the python syntax of every line that starts with the interpreter symbol (>>>) and any other line is simply reported in black.

I have figured out that `lstlistings` provide its own way to create specialized environments with the `lstnewenvironment{}` command, here's an example:

```
\lstnewenvironment{interp}{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Interp} \lstset{language=Python, numbers=none,\color{lightgreen}, basicstyle=\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont}}
{}
```

Is there any slick trick to print any line apart the first in black?